# Why LookupAccountSid is giving weird Security Descriptor data in Win32 API using C?

Tags: c, winapi

I am trying to fetch the correct SID (principal) name for each SACL instance (for security auditing) in Windows using the native `LookupAccountSid` WinAPI function.

See screenshot below of one example file I want to test:

[image]

But my code produces incorrect information as shown below:

[image]

Below is what should have happened.

```
sidName = Everyone, size = 9
sidName = Everyone, size = 9
sidName = trevm, size = 6
```

I think I have followed the MSDN documentation carefully but it is not helping?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-lookupaccountsidw

My code can obtain the Security Descriptor using `GetSecurityDescriptorSacl` without no problem, but the `LookupAccountSid` is problematic. What have I gone wrong? Below is my C code. Anyone knows why?

```
int getSACLinfo(HANDLE rToken, SE_OBJECT_TYPE objectType, ACEVALUE*& aceRef, int* count)
{
    int arrSize = 0;
    int retVal = ERROR_SUCCESS;
    PACL sacl = NULL;
    SYSTEM_AUDIT_ACE* ace = NULL;
    PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR pSS = NULL;
    PSID sid;
    PSID sidOwner;
    BOOL saclPresent;
    BOOL saclDefaulted;
    wchar_t sidName[512];
    wchar_t domainName[512];

    ULONG result = GetSecurityInfo(rToken, objectType,
        OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION | SACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION | LABEL_SECURITY_INFORMATION,
        &sidOwner, NULL, NULL, &sacl, &pSS);

    if (result == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        /* Get SACL security descriptor */
        GetSecurityDescriptorSacl(pSS, &saclPresent, &sacl, &saclDefaulted);

        if (saclPresent && (sacl != NULL))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < sacl->AceCount; i++)
            {
                GetAce(sacl, i, (PVOID*)&ace);

                /* Get SID from Ace */
                sid = (PSID)&ace->SidStart;

                if (IsValidSid(sid) && ace->Header.AceType == SYSTEM_AUDIT_ACE_TYPE)
                {
                    arrSize++;
                }
            }

            // Allocate memory for the data structures to be exported
            aceRef = (ACEVALUE*)malloc(arrSize * sizeof(ACEVALUE));

            if (arrSize > 0 && aceRef != NULL)
            {
                size_t len;
                wchar_t* buf;
                DWORD namelen;
                DWORD domainnamelen;
                SID_NAME_USE peUse;

                for (int i = 0; i < sacl->AceCount; i++)
                {
                    GetAce(sacl, i, (PVOID*)&ace);

                    sid = (PSID)&ace->SidStart;

                    if (IsValidSid(sid) && ace->Header.AceType == SYSTEM_AUDIT_ACE_TYPE)
                    {
                        LookupAccountSid(NULL, sid, sidName, &namelen, domainName, &domainnamelen, &peUse);

                        wprintf(L"sidName = %s, size = %d\n", sidName, namelen);

                        len = wcslen(sidName) + 1;
                        buf = (wchar_t*)malloc(len * sizeof(wchar_t));

                        if (buf != NULL)
                        {
                            wcscpy_s(buf, len, sidName);
                            aceRef[i].Name = buf;
                        }

                        aceRef[i].AceMask = ace->Mask;
                        aceRef[i].AceType = ace->Header.AceType;
                        aceRef[i].AceFlags = ace->Header.AceFlags;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    else
    {
        retVal = GetLastError();
    }

    *count = arrSize;

    if (pSS != NULL)
    {
        LocalFree((HLOCAL)pSS);
        wprintf(L"FREED!\n");
    }

    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: You seem to be experiencing undefined behavior. Some memory mishandled caused corruption, probably. You need a memory debugger, there is a very good one that I could recommend but it doesn't work on WIndows. You have to find one, I think there should be a good one but I haven't ever found it.

Comment: you not initialize `namelen` and `domainnamelen` before call `LookupAccountSid` which is always wrong, you not check result of this api

Comment: Are you saying I should initialise these 2 variables with some value first?

Comment: Yes! They should be set to the size of the buffers. They will be overwritten, only if the buffer is too small, in which case they will have the size you need. If you call with zeroes first, then you can use the values to dynamically allocate the correct sized buffer. Read the documentation you pointed to.

Comment: of course, and not with some values, but with your input buffer size in symbols. also code is very not optimized. for what you say call `GetSecurityDescriptorSacl` when you already have sacl from call `GetSecurityInfo`, etc

Comment: Thank you for pointing out. After some further research, yes, my code with `LookupAccountSid` was incomplete. I will post my updated code that can now reach the correct information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Below is the updated code to rectify my mistake. After doing further research, I learnt that the problem was due to the fact that I did not specify the buffer size for the 2 variables: *namelen* and *domainnamelen* in my original code (Thanks to @RbMm and @jwdonahue for pointing out).

```
DWORD getSACLinfo(HANDLE rToken, SE_OBJECT_TYPE objectType, ACEVALUE*& aceRef, int* count)
{
    size_t len;
    int arrSize = 0;
    wchar_t* buf;
    wchar_t* sidName = NULL;
    wchar_t* domainName = NULL;
    PSID sid;
    PSID sidOwner;
    PACL sacl = NULL;
    DWORD retValue;
    DWORD dwRevision;
    DWORD namelen;
    DWORD domainnamelen;
    SYSTEM_AUDIT_ACE* ace = NULL;
    PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR pSS = NULL;
    SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_CONTROL sdControl;

    /* Get SACL security descriptor */
    retValue = GetSecurityInfo(rToken, objectType,
        OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION | SACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION | LABEL_SECURITY_INFORMATION,
        &sidOwner, NULL, NULL, &sacl, &pSS);

    if (retValue == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        if (GetSecurityDescriptorControl(pSS, &sdControl, &dwRevision) == FALSE)
        {
            retValue = ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION;
        }

        else if (sacl != NULL && (sdControl & SE_SACL_PRESENT) == SE_SACL_PRESENT)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < sacl->AceCount; i++)
            {
                GetAce(sacl, i, (PVOID*)&ace);

                /* Get SID from Ace */
                sid = (PSID)&ace->SidStart;

                if (IsValidSid(sid) && ace->Header.AceType == SYSTEM_AUDIT_ACE_TYPE)
                {
                    arrSize++;
                }
            }

            // Allocate memory for the data structures to be exported
            aceRef = (ACEVALUE*)malloc(arrSize * sizeof(ACEVALUE));

            if (arrSize > 0 && aceRef != NULL)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < sacl->AceCount; i++)
                {
                    GetAce(sacl, i, (PVOID*)&ace);

                    sid = (PSID)&ace->SidStart;

                    if (IsValidSid(sid) && ace->Header.AceType == SYSTEM_AUDIT_ACE_TYPE)
                    {
                        // ADDED TO FIX THE PROBLEM
                        getNameBySID(sid, sidName, &namelen, domainName, &domainnamelen);

                        wprintf(L"size = %d, Owner = %s\n", namelen, sidName);

                        len = wcslen(sidName) + 1;
                        buf = (wchar_t*)malloc(len * sizeof(wchar_t));

                        if (buf != NULL)
                        {
                            wcscpy_s(buf, len, sidName);
                            aceRef[i].Name = buf;
                        }

                        aceRef[i].AceMask = ace->Mask;
                        aceRef[i].AceType = ace->Header.AceType;
                        aceRef[i].AceFlags = ace->Header.AceFlags;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    else
    {
        retValue = GetLastError();
    }

    *count = arrSize;

    // Memory deallocations
    free(sidName);
    free(domainName);
    LocalFree((HLOCAL)pSS);

    wprintf(L"FREED!\n");

    return retValue;
}
```

To fix, I added a new function `getNameBySID` so it provides the correct memory space for the buffers *sidName* and *domainName*. The logic simply involves a do-while loop to continue the iteration until it satisfies the requirement of `LookupAccountSid` where the  buffer size is correct for these 2 buffers. If the previous buffer size is too small for the buffer to be filled up, it frees up the previously allocated buffer and then re-allocates with the correct size and tries again.

```
DWORD getNameBySID(PSID sid, wchar_t *&oNameBuf, DWORD *owNameSize, wchar_t *&dNameBuf, DWORD *dnNameSize)
{
    const DWORD DEFAULT_SIZE = 256;
    const wchar_t NONAME[] = L"Unknown";

    bool status;
    SID_NAME_USE peUse;
    DWORD retValue;
    DWORD ownerBufSize = *owNameSize;
    DWORD domainBufSize = *dnNameSize;

    // Create buffers that may be large enough
    if (oNameBuf == NULL || dNameBuf == NULL)
    {
        ownerBufSize = domainBufSize = DEFAULT_SIZE;

        oNameBuf = (wchar_t*)malloc(ownerBufSize * sizeof(wchar_t));
        dNameBuf = (wchar_t*)malloc(domainBufSize * sizeof(wchar_t));

        if (oNameBuf == NULL)
        {
            return ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER;
        }

        if (dNameBuf == NULL)
        {
            free(oNameBuf);
            return ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER;
        }

        *owNameSize = ownerBufSize;
        *dnNameSize = domainBufSize;

        memset(oNameBuf, 0, ownerBufSize * sizeof(wchar_t));
        memset(dNameBuf, 0, domainBufSize * sizeof(wchar_t));
    }

    do
    {
        status = (LookupAccountSid(NULL, sid, oNameBuf, owNameSize, dNameBuf, dnNameSize, &peUse) == TRUE);

        if (!status)
        {
            retValue = GetLastError();

            if (*owNameSize > ownerBufSize)
            {
                // Reallocate memory for the buffer and try again.
                //wprintf(L"The account name buffer was too small. It will be reallocated.\n");
                free(oNameBuf);

                oNameBuf = (wchar_t*)malloc(*owNameSize * sizeof(wchar_t));

                if (oNameBuf == NULL)
                {
                    return ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER;
                }

                ownerBufSize = *owNameSize;
                memset(oNameBuf, 0, ownerBufSize * sizeof(wchar_t));
            }

            else if (*dnNameSize > domainBufSize)
            {
                // Reallocate memory for the buffer and try again.
                //wprintf(L"The domain name buffer was too small. It will be reallocated.\n");
                free(dNameBuf);

                dNameBuf = (wchar_t*)malloc(*dnNameSize * sizeof(wchar_t));

                if (dNameBuf == NULL)
                {
                    return ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER;
                }

                domainBufSize = *dnNameSize;
                memset(dNameBuf, 0, domainBufSize * sizeof(wchar_t));
            }

            else if (retValue == ERROR_NONE_MAPPED)
            {
                // A name could not be found for the SID due to an unexpected error occurred.
                if (ownerBufSize > wcslen(NONAME))
                {
                    wcscpy_s(oNameBuf, wcslen(NONAME) + 1, NONAME);
                    oNameBuf[wcslen(NONAME)] = L'\0';
                }

                dNameBuf[0] = L'\0';
                break;
            }

            else
            {
                wprintf(L"LookupAccountSid failed. GetLastError returned: %d\n", retValue);
                break;
            }
        }

    } while (!status);

    *owNameSize = ownerBufSize;
    *dnNameSize = domainBufSize;

    return (status ? ERROR_SUCCESS : retValue);
}
```

Basically, my `getSACLinfo` function remains mostly the same, except for calling `getNameBySID` to get the correctly sized buffers for these 2 names.

Below produces the expected information.

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify what changes you had to make, so that the source of the problem is clearer? That way people won't have to diff the two code blocks to see what the problem was and how to fix it.

Comment: @Raymond Chen, I have updated my answer hopefully it has clarified the source of the problem.